# Calculate Liters Remaining in a CO2 gas cylinder/bottle

Tags: ideal-gas, gas

**I know:**

The gas is CO2 (very close to 100% CO2)

V - The Volume of the Cylinder (constant)

P - The pressure of the Cylinder (from a sensor)

T - The temperature of the Cylinder (from a sensor)

**I want to know:**

How many liters of CO2 remain in the Cylinder.  Liters based on the room temperature and pressure.  (1atm and room temperature might be a safe assumption)

First I thought I could use the Ideal Gas Laws to calculate this, however,
the gas Cylinder is under very high pressure > 1200psi and CO2 will not behave
as an ideal gas under these conditions.

How can I solve this using only what I have for sensors?  Ex. without adding
a scale to measure Cylinder weight.   Is it possible?

Comment: At least some of the $CO_2$ will be in liquid form at that pressure and room temperature, but you won't know how much is liquid and how much gas without weighing the cylinder.